# Linting: Comparing Verilog Parameter and Constant String

Tags: string, parameters, verilog

We have a module xxx with a string parameter.

```
module xxx;
parameter PAR = "bad"

generate
if (PAR == "abc") begin

end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

We instatitates the module and pass a parameter value.

```
xxx #(.PAR("abcd")) u_xxx;
```

The linting tool will complain about the line. The PAR value "abcd" is 32-bit, but "abc" is 24-bit.

```
if (PAR == "abc") begin
```

Is there a good soultion to resolve the linting issue?

Answer (score 0):

Verilog treats every 'char' as an 8-bit entity. So, width of a string parameter is defined by multiplication of 8 by the number of chars.

In plain verilog there is no way around it. So, linting tools might complain. Comparison on the other hand, should work ok. Verilog will zero-extend missing bits. So, you can just waive the lint message.

In plain 'verilog' there is no good solution for this linting problem. The best one is to forget strings and switch to integers.

```
parameter abc = 0;
parameter abcd = 1;
...
if (PAR == abc) ...
```

The other solution is to switch to SystemVerilog and define the type of the parameter as 'string' or define its max width in bits.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using SystemVerilog (you might already be using it and not know it), and declare your parameter as a string

```
module xxx;
parameter string PAR="abc";
```

or use a lint waiver

```
if (PAR == "abc") begin // lint ignore this
```

check your lint tool manual for the correct syntax

Comment: OP did not tag it as system verilog. No strings.

Comment: @Serge, I know , but that is a possible solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog doesn't have a `string` type; SystemVerilog does; Verilog converts each charactor in to 8-bits using ASCII encoding. That is why it sees `"abc"` as 24-bits.

You can front load zeros to make Verilog accept a 32-bit (4 character) values, with the the default value still using 24-bits (4 character).

```
parameter PAR = {8'h00,"abc"}; // 32-bits or 4 characters
```

Or, assuming you are not stuck with Verilog-95, you specify the range or make it an `interger` type (See IEEE1364-2001 § 3.11.1 *Module parameters*)

```
parameter [31:0]  PAR1 = "abc";
parameter integer PAR2 = "abc";
```

SystemVerilog (which supersets Verilog) gives you more options. [IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 6.20 *Constants*